# Difference between transitionfromview and addsubview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` similar to `[self.view addSubview:secondView];`

**RootViewController.m**

```
self.svc = [[secondVC alloc]init];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.svc.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

is similar to

**RootViewController.m**

```
        self.svc = [[secondVC alloc]init];

    [self.view addSubView:self.svc];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut.............
```

does first approach can lead to memory leaks? is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` if you switch from one view to another and want to discard the first one. If you add additional views to your view you should use `addSubview:`

Comment: Please look at the code again, in transitionfromview I am trying to display the view which belong to secondviewcontroller, its not in the hierarchy. Doing this is correct?

Comment: I would add the view to view hierarchie and the second controller to view controller hierarchie.

Comment: I would like to invite you to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657719/please-clear-some-confusions-regarding-uiviewcontroller